# Missing children in XML parsed by SimpleXML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Here is the XML I am parsing:
https://seekingalpha.com/api/sa/combined/AAPL.xml

When I grab and parse the XML with simplexml_load_file($url) and then do a var_dump on that, it shows that the only children of every "item" are "title", "link", "guid", and "pubDate."

I am trying to access the node "sa:author_name." Why isn't it a child of "item"? Maybe I am misunderstanding something about how XML files are structured. Help me my children are missing lol

Comment: find about using namespace in xml on the site or in internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data in `sa:author_name` you have to use the namespace `https://seekingalpha.com/api/1.0`.

You can for example use a `foreach` and loop the [children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) using the namespace.

```
$url = "https://seekingalpha.com/api/sa/combined/AAPL.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    foreach ($item->children("https://seekingalpha.com/api/1.0") as $child) {
        if ($child->getName() === "author_name") {
            echo $child . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Another way you could do it is using an [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) expression:

```
$authorNames = $xml->xpath('/rss/channel/item/sa:author_name');

foreach ($authorNames as $authorName) {
    echo $authorName . "<br>";
}
```

Which will result in:

```
Yoel Minkoff
DoctoRx
SA Transcripts
Bill Maurer
etc..
```